# How to extend terminate timeout in Yate iaxengine?

Tags: yate, iax

Yate service fails after this output to the log:

```
2023-11-22_22:48:48.000058 <iaxengine:INFO> Status changed Listening -> Exiting [0x1ace6c0]
2023-11-22_22:48:48.000074 <iaxengine:ALL> Set terminate timeout=16500ms status=Exiting [0x1ace6c0]
2023-11-22_22:48:48.000090 <iax:INFO> Removed listener (0x1ace6c0) 'iaxengine' status='Exiting'
```

How we can increase timeout from 16500ms to larger value?